# How to do horizontal slice between views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm looking for some advice about the best way to create a multi-view iPhone application. This app will slice left to right and right to left when a it goes from one view to another. Very similar to how a navigation-based application but without the navigation top bar.

I'm doing some tests using this code:

```
- (IBAction)goToSettings:(id)sender {    

    SettingsViewController *controller = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

something like **UIModalTransitionStyleCoverHorizontal** which doesn't exist.

So, I'm trying to do transitions, but now sure if that's the best way to do it, in terms of memory management, etc.

In summary, my application will have ~8 views, and I need to be able to navigate between them, going left to right into details, and go back to the left (previous view). What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar is optional in a navigation-based application. UINavigationController has a `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

If for some reason that won't work, an alternative might be a paging UIScrollView, but that would be more hacky and more work to get what UINavigationController already gives you.

Comment: would it be posible to change the UITableView for a UIView in a brand new navigation-based application? or is UITableView part of the  navigation-based application?

Comment: They are separate - UITableViews are often used inside UINavigationControllers, but that's not necessary, you can use any other kind of UIView instead.